# Connecting android studio emulator to springboot backend

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, android-emulator

I am doing a project of connecting the android studio emulator using flutter to my backend springboot database thru http request. The data is in my database but yet the http request from the emulator is receiving error that no data was found. The ip address i used for was 10.0.2.2 which is what i found online. May i ask if anyone has faced such issue before?